# SMTP server force outbound traffic

Tags: php, networking, tcp, smtp, windows

I'm having some trouble with setting up a SMTP server on a windows server 2003 machine, while trying to send emails using PHP through the internet, but to domain email addresses.

**Common info:**

- Machine has Windows Server 2003 Server
- Machine on a domain (mydomain.com)
- Machine is not a domain controller
- Machine accesses a domain controller through the internet (WAN with a corporate VPN link by the internet provider setup on the machine's gateway - adsl modem/router)
- Email addresses use the same suffix (mydomain.com)
- Do not have access to domain controller configuration

**First Scenario**

- TCP/IP DNS: 1st 192.168.200.xxx   2nd 8.8.8.8
- Direct access to domain controller is functional
- PHP mail using localhost to a user@mydomain.com won't work, because the remote mail server rejects emails from internal traffic (apparently!?!)

**Second Scenario**

- TCP/IP DNS: 1st  8.8.8.8   2nd 192.168.200.xxx   (**switched**)
- Direct access to domain controller is **not** functional, only local accounts work
- PHP mail using localhost to a user@mydomain.com **does** work, because the remote mail server is accessed through its internet/external address.

So, what I needed is to have both (1) access to the domain controller and (2) PHP mail using localhost to a user@mydomain.com account working.

Any pointers? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the machine have a local MTA? Or does PHP have to make an outgoing connection to some other SMTP system for sending mail?

Comment: @sarnold I've setup a SMTP virtual server on this machine and I'm trying to send emails using that server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used hMailserver to route SMTP traffic to the email server I wanted, and disabled the IIS SMTP server.

Thanks for the input anyway

Answer (score 0):

Since the DNS at 192.168.200.xxx is local, it probably resolves host names to local (192.168.200.xxx) IP addresses.  The DNS at 8.8.8.8 is external, so it resolves host names to their FQDN.

The best solution is to have your outbound mail server rewrite the senders' addresses to use the FQDN instead of the local host/network names.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. The first part is what I understood so far. I really have no idea on how you to that address "rewrite" or whats FQDN... Can you give something more specific? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I might have completely misunderstood what you are saying, but I would suggest setting the smtp host settings in php.ini to your ISP smtp server like so;

```
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp
SMTP = your-smtp-server.yourisp.com
```

Then php in scenario 1) php will send email externally, and not be confused by the AD domain with the same name as the MX record for user@mydomain.com

Comment: I think this will send emails using that external SMTP server. Even though I could use this in another way, I am actually trying to send email using this machine (localhost), which is not getting accepted by the receiver server

Comment: oh, then paste the bounce message and we can tell you what needs to change